# Embed excel in Wordpress page

Tags: excel, wordpress

I managed to embed an excel file in a wordpress page with the instructions I found here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-onedrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

But then I see all the tabs of that file.
Is it possible to embed only one of the tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed only a range of data (like a single sheet) using OneDrive you have to open the file on OneDrive and go to "File > Share > Embed".

Then from the "Embed" dialog you can choose what range you want to share, as example if you want to share only some columns/rows for a specific sheet you can write `'Sheet A'!A1:B4`

[image: OneDrive Share / Embed]
[image: One Drive Embed dialog]

Comment: The solution works fine.
I can also can change the button to download from true to false in the code (don't want to do that).
But I can not hide the option to see the whole map (I only want to show a particular part).
And Also hide the scroll.

Comment: Does anybody know how to secure the file without the option to see the URL or the option to download? There is the option to embed with the Java script, but that is not available on onedrive personal. So can I convert the embed code to Java?