# embed google sheet, only part

Tags: excel, google-sheets, embed

In an earlier post I tryed to find a solution for embedding an excel sheet from onedrive
([Embed excel in Wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796704/embed-excel-in-wordpress-page/76796976#76796976)).
But there are issues about privacy: you can hyde in the embed code the url to download, but it will still be possible.
The suggestion to use javascript is only available in onedrive for bussiness.

I'm trying to find a work around.
So I try to embed google sheets.
And there I think is no option to see the url.

You can embed the whole file or 1 sheet.
But is there also a way to embed a part of a sheet (like in the onedrive)?

Comment: Is this for Excel? If not why tag it?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post there is a privacy issue with embedding excel sheets.

Comment: I think I have the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446449/google-sheet-embed-url-documentation?rq=2